# Unity hangs when adding a GameObject to a List

Tags: unity

Since 3 days ago Unity started freezing after adding a GameObject to a List. I haven't changed anything in that particular code, so I have no idea why this is happening:

```
 private IEnumerator HandleSelectedCubes() {
    if (InputManager.instance.selectedCube != null && !selectedCubes.Contains(InputManager.instance.selectedCube)) {
        if (oldSelectedCube == null) {
            selectedCubes.Add(InputManager.instance.selectedCube); // This is where it crashes
            oldSelectedCube = InputManager.instance.selectedCube;
        } else if (InputManager.instance.selectedCube.name != oldSelectedCube.name) {
            ClearSelectedCubes();
            selectedCubes.Add(InputManager.instance.selectedCube);
            oldSelectedCube = InputManager.instance.selectedCube;
            InputManager.instance.selectedCube = null;
        }

        AudioManager.instance.PlayCubeSelectSound();

        if (selectedCubes.Count == 4) {
            InputManager.instance.allowCubeSelection = false;
            moveDone = true;
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.07f);

            var destroySelectedCubes = true;

            foreach (var cube in selectedCubes.ToList()) {
                if (cube != null && cube.tag == "Lightning")
                    destroySelectedCubes = false;
            }

            foreach (var cube in selectedCubes.ToList()) {
                if (cube != null) {
                    cube.GetComponent<Cube>().hasGivenShard = true;
                    CubeAbilities.instance.TriggerSpecialCubeAbility(cube);

                    if (destroySelectedCubes) {
                        DestroyCube(cube);
                        ClearSelectedCubes();
                    }
                }
            }

            InputManager.instance.playerMovesCount++;
            AudioManager.instance.PlayCubeDisappearSound();
            ShardManager.instance.AddSessionShards(4);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Since you mentioned you haven't changed that code let me ask: have you changed any code related to selectedCubes? Modifying the list anywhere else? Delete the list or the gameobject holding it? Enabling / disabling the gameobject / script somewhere else in code?

Comment: Since it does not throw exceptions but crashes my best bet is that you are trying to access the list but have already destroyed / deleted the game object or don't have it yet initialized.

Comment: @monty - Both of those should throw an exception, though.  In both cases you should get an object reference exception.

Comment: If you debug and step into this, does it die anywhere in particular?  First rule of debugging - always talk about your debugging.  :)

Comment: @monty I put a debug.log on the objects and they appear. Also, I doubt Unity will crash just because a simple GameObject doesn't exist. Maybe it does a weird loop. I will test it more tomorrow :)

Comment: Well, I just gave hints what it could be. :-) Since you said you haven't changed that code you gave the problem must be somewhere else. Does the game now hang or crash?

Comment: @monty Hangs, to the point where I have to end the process from Task Manager

Comment: @Milen: freezes tend to be infinite loops (http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/258230/c-script-makes-unity-freeze-on-arraylistadd.html) and (http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/288977/unity-freezes-when-i-add-a-special-script.html)

Comment: The thing it happens only one, since I check in the Input script if the selected cube is the same. So just by adding the object to the list crashes it. It's so odd.